# Combined results from relationship in WanWizard datamapper orm?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have a relationship that is setup like so:

a user has multiple roles
a role has multiple modules
Hence, a user has all modules that their roles have

Basically what I want to do is given the user get back all modules that the user has.

How can I do this with the datamapper ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article relating to deep relationships: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#Deep.Relationship.Queries

You would do something along the lines of

```
$modules = new Module();
$modules->where_related('role/user', 'id', $userid)->get();
```